# Unit testing about API endpoints and parameters

Tags: unit-testing, web-api, integration-tests

Consider a simple web application, I'll use a Python(ish) example, but i think the question is relevant for other languages as well.

The user is trying to fetch a page, and in order to render that page, the application has to make an external call to a remote service. In the example, I'll try to separate concerns: collecting input parameters, and calling the actual remote service.

```py
def view(request):
  foo = float(request.POST['foo'])
  return Response(process_foo(foo))

def process_foo(foo):
  return remote_service.get('/bar', data={'foo': foo})
```

In the example, `view` is a function that's responsible for transforming the incoming `request` to a `Response`, and `process_foo` is responsible for performing some business logic.

What kind of unit tests make sense here?

A few preferences:

- In `view`, I'd expect `process_foo` to be a black-box, so I'd like to replace it with something during testing, so I can refactor `process_foo` without breaking unit tests for `view`.
- In `process_foo`, I'd like to replace the call `remote_service.get`, as it's an expensive operation.

Considering the restrictions above, I'm not sure what kinds of unit tests make sense here. In `view`, I could make an assertion about that `process_foo` was called with `foo`, but when I make changes to `process_foo`, this test will not break. The same is true for testing `process_foo`: if I make an assertion on that `remote_service.get` was called with the right URL and the right parameters, that'll not break when the remote URL changes (or it no longer accepts the same parameters).

To me it feels like that somehow I should test that `foo` was extracted from `request.POST`, but it seems that there's no reasonable way to do this.

I'm aware that integration tests can solve this problem, I'm looking for a possible solution about how the problem above could be solved with unit tests (if there's a solution at all).

Comment: not sure i understand your problem. Whats wrong with comparing the returned object from each function with an expected response. if it matches, pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ideas make sense.

> In view, I could make an assertion about that process_foo was called with foo, but when I make changes to process_foo, this test will not break.

So it is a good thing that `process_foo` has its own tests that will fail on an improper refactoring.

> if I make an assertion on that remote_service.get was called with the right URL and the right parameters, that'll not break when the remote URL changes (or it no longer accepts the same parameters).

If you are concerned about how an external program responds to what you give it, you pretty much by definition are writing an integration test, not a unit test. It is not in the scope of unit testing to detect if an external API changes.

> To me it feels like that somehow I should test that foo was extracted from request.POST, but it seems that there's no reasonable way to do this.

Python makes this easy. You just make your own object that has a dictionary attribute named `POST` and load it with whatever data you need. When you call `view` with it, mock out `process_foo`, and use [`assert_called_once_with()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_once)

Finally, if you wish to treat `process_foo()` as a black-blox within `view()`, consider refactoring to make it clear this is an "external" dependency. I generally consider using `mock.patch` to be a code smell (which doesn't mean that it's never the right choice!)

Comment: I see. Would it make sense to swap (`mock.patch`) `process_foo` out with some kind of dummy implementation, and assert instead of the return value of `view`? That way I could avoid the `assert_called_once_with` call (which I consider a code smell).

Comment: I think I like that better, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm aware that integration tests can solve this problem, I'm looking for a possible solution about how the problem above could be solved with unit tests (if there's a solution at all).

Where I would start from is a minor re-design.

```
def process_foo(foo):
  return remote_service.get('/bar', data={'foo': foo})
```

The problem here is that we're combining computation and logic (which you want to test) with an expensive side effect (which you don't).

A common answer here is "configurable dependencies", which is a hipster spelling of "dependency injection", which in turn is just a pretentious way of saying "pass an argument".

```
def process_foo(foo, remote_service):
  return remote_service.get('/bar', data={'foo': foo})
```

This implementation allows you, in your test, to provide an *inexpensive* implementation of the remote service (for instance, a test double that just returns a constant).

If the expensive side effect is coming by way of a third party library, then `remote_service` won't usually be the third party client itself, but your own wrapper around it.

```
def get(uri, data):
    return third_party_client.get(uri, data)
```

This kind of wrapper is probably more common in languages like Java with a compiler that is fussy about types.  It sometimes looks a bit odd (why bother?), but the motivation is that only a relatively small amount of our code should be coupled to the decision that we have made about how to implement our connection -- see [Parnas 1972](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/05/on-the-criteria-to-be-used-in-decomposing-systems-into-modules/).

Note that this wrapper is deliberately simple; the third party client being relatively expensive to test means that this code isn't going to be tested as often, and we want to mitigate the risks.

Comment: replacing `remote_service` with a mock is not an issue, python has standard tools for this (`patch`). i also agree that dependency injection makes this a bit easier. i just wasn't sure if it's worth to make an assertion on that `remote_service.get` was called with the right params, as the tests won't break in case the remote service API changes. i think in general it's worth to make such  assertions (so you can refactor with confidence), but that alone won't be sufficient to refactor `remote_service`, you _need_ integration tests for that.